# What is "AUTH" in Redis and how to use it?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster

What is "AUTH" in Redis and how to use and when to use it. It will be helpful if you provide a few examples.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Specifically https://redis.io/commands/auth

Answer (score 1):

The AUTH command is used to prevent unauthorized access to a Redis instance. You specify a password in the Redis config file. A client that wants to connect to the Redis instance must first call the AUTH command with the correct password in which case the server replies with the OK status code and starts accepting commands.  If the password is incorrect or the AUTH command is not called first, all subsequent calls to the Redis instance fail.

Example:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH abcd@1234
```